# LINQ how to order on a referenced List

Tags: linq, sorting

I have an object as defined like this

```
 public class Person {
    public Person() {
        this.NewsItems = new List<NewsItem>();
    }
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; }

}
```

The NewsItem object has a property called DisplayOrder and it is of type int. I then have LINQ as following:

```
 return _repo.GetAll<Person>().Where(p => p.age >60).ToList();
```

My objective is have a sorted `List<Person>`  based on DisplayOrder.

I am going to use this `List<Person>` in controller. In this controller I do have access to `Person.NewsItems`. I need to have `List<Person>` to be sorted in order or DisplayOrder which is inside the referenced list NewsItems.

Basically I have 1:m relationship between Person and NewsItem.

Comment: you need to clarify how the display order is used. it is a collection. will they each have the same or different values for that property and which one do we sort on

Comment: display order is int type property and may have same or different value. I want sort Person in order of display item. I want to use it `Person.NewsItem[i].Title`

Comment: What determines `i` in the snippet provided in your last comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom comparer that you can use with `.OrderBy`. This could be against the `NewsItems` property. So you can do something like:

```
 var sortedPersons = persons
            .Where(p => p.Age > 60)
            .OrderBy(x => x.NewsItems, new NewsItemsComparer());
```

Where your `NewsItemComparer` could take the form of:

```
public class NewsItemsComparer : IComparer<IList<NewsItem>>
{
    public int Compare(IList<NewsItem> x, IList<NewsItem> y)
    {
        if (<logic where xDisplayOrders takes precedence over yDisplay Orders>)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (<logic where yDisplayOrders takes precedence over xDisplay Orders>)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample implementation in which Persons are sorted according to which NewsItems has the lowest DisplayOrder number: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MTtwHU

Comment: I appreciate your response. Let me give it a try and i will update the forum.

Comment: No worries. Let me know how it goes or if you need more info on the sample code. Cheers!